# CrUX API - 404 NOT_FOUND for valid domains

Tags: chrome-ux-report

### CrUX Demo Code - giving a 404 for major public sites?

I'm trying to run the sample code from Google's [CrUX API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/api) page.  The code:

```js
const CrUXApiUtil = {};
// Get your CrUX API key at https://goo.gle/crux-api-key.
CrUXApiUtil.API_KEY = 'MY_KEY_REDACTED';
CrUXApiUtil.API_ENDPOINT = `https://chromeuxreport.googleapis.com/v1/records:queryRecord?key=${CrUXApiUtil.API_KEY}`;
CrUXApiUtil.query = function (requestBody) {
  if (CrUXApiUtil.API_KEY == '[YOUR_API_KEY]') {
    throw 'Replace "YOUR_API_KEY" with your private CrUX API key. Get a key at https://goo.gle/crux-api-key.';
  }
  return fetch(CrUXApiUtil.API_ENDPOINT, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
    if (response.error) {
      return Promise.reject(response);
    }
    return response;
  });
};

CrUXApiUtil.query({
    origin: 'https://developers.google.com'
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(response => {
    console.error(response);
  });
```

That produces a good result, as do **SOME** other `origin` values for major websites.

The result with data is inconsistent.

It works for `facebook.com` and `web.dev` and `developers.google.com`.

It gives a 404 error for `nytimes.com`, `cleveland.com`, `ticketmaster.com` and several other sites that are not trivially small (including several where I work).

### Things I Tried:

- Verified all of the 404s from my code are valid in PageSpeed Insights [example](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-ticketmaster-com/zzjz82qpgc?form_factor=mobile).
- Verified our company origins are generating data in Search Console (i.e. it's not just our domains).
- Set the Google Cloud API key to unrestricted (while testing).
- Double-check the Chrome UX Report API is getting queries (it is) and shows successes for the domains listed above (facebook, web.dev, etc) and failures for the others.
- tried using `url` instead of `origin` for a specific page for domains generating a 404.  Same error.

I'm guessing I'm either misunderstanding the Cloud API Key setup, or there's a permission in Search Console I can't see or lack as I'm not a full admin in Search Console.  (But, for both, why would it work for `facebook.com` or `web.dev` as I don't have access to their Search Console....)

### Example Error

```json
{
  error: {
    code: 404,
    message: 'chrome ux report data not found',
    status: 'NOT_FOUND'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each origin is treated as unique in CrUX. So `example.com`, `www.example.com`,  and `blog.example.com` are all different origins in CrUX. Some of which may be in the CrUX dataset, and some of which may not, depending on whether they are visited by sufficient users.

Importantly, an origin is not the same as a registrable domain.

> It gives a 404 error for `nytimes.com`, `cleveland.com`, `ticketmaster.com` and several other sites that are not trivially small (including several where I work).

None of those are websites that serve content - they all redirect to other origins. `https://www.nytimes.com`, `https://www.cleveland.com`, and `https://www.ticketmaster.com` however all return results from CrUX.

Some CrUX tools like PageSpeed Insights will check for redirects but the API does not (however it will ["normalize"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/api#api-response-urlnormalization) the URL to just that origin by removing trailing slashes and paths, for example).

Comment: Yep.  I got sloppy and some tunnel vision and used the 'friendly' url from the browser rather than expanding it to confirm where things were redirecting.  Thanks!

Comment: I hate the fact the browsers hide www (ad https://) for this reason. But apparently I'm in the minority... :-(